# azure virtual machine subdomain

Tags: azure, subdomain, virtual-machine, cname

I have a virtual machine on azure that I want to host a site on that is a sub-domain (mysite.contoso.com) of my main/root site (www.contoso.com).  My main site is hosted on Arvixe and works just fine.  GoDaddy is my registrar.

I have setup the site on the VM and tested it locally.  It works perfectly.  I have added a CNAME record on GoDaddy that points my subdomain (mysite) to my VM (myVM.cloudapp.net).  I have added an endpoint to azure for my VM to accept requests on port 80.

When I ping my subdomain, I get the IP Address of my root site and I get "Web Page Unavailable" when I attempt to browse to it.  For testing purposes I added a host file entry for my subdomain that points to the VM external IP and everything works perfectly.  Once I remove the host file entry, it fails again.

What am I missing here?  It appears that the site and endpoint for the VM is setup correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Comment: Check again your DNS configuration on GoDaddy. If "hosts file" on your PC works then the VM on Azure is OK. So, check the DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't know what else to do with the DNS on GoDaddy.  I added the CNAME record and it still doesn't work.  Are there other settings that you are implying I should check?  If so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my domain was never successfully transferred to Arvixe.  I completed the domain transfer, added the CNAME record through Arvixe, and now my site works perfectly.